# How to format my date with SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I'm trying to set a date format, but when i run this code

```
String oldstring = "2013-01-1";
System.out.println("oldstring = "+oldstring);
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse(oldstring);
System.out.println("datefield = "+date);
```

i take result:

```
oldstring = 2013-01-1
datefield = Tue Jan 01 00:01:00 MSK 2013
```

Why datefield isn't equal 2013-01-1?

Comment: Just curious, when you already have the date in yyyy-MM-dd format, why do you want to format it again?

Comment: for my datefield in vaadin. I want to set it 2013-01-01

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of datefield is Date, so the toString method will basically always return the same format, as you are not overriding it.

So what you need to do, is basically:

```
String oldstring = "2013-01-1";
System.out.println("oldstring = "+oldstring);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = sdf.parse(oldstring);
System.out.println("datefield = "+date);
String outDateStr = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println("newstring = "+outDateStr);
```

Answer (score 4):

At first `mm` in `yyyy-mm-dd` mean minute not Month. to set month use `MM`.

It would be look like this :

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(oldstring);
```

**UPDATE**
Try this:

```
String oldstring = "2013-01-1";
System.out.println("oldstring = "+oldstring);
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse(oldstring);
String sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").format(date);
System.out.println("datefield = "+sdf);
```

If you don't use `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").format(date);` 
you getting standard date format which include all info. If you want special format you need to use
`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").format(date);`

[Also read this article about date formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use MM for month. mm is for minutes

Comment: you should use `format` instead of `parse`. `String newDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);`